# License symbol not exported in Android kernel module object

Tags: android, linux-kernel, kernel-module

When building this simple example Android kernel module

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>    

int init_module(void)
    {
      return 0;
    }

void cleanup_module(void)
    {
      printk("exit module.");
    }

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("jckuester");
```

for kernel `2.6.35.7-gf5f63ef` (used for the quite old Android version 2.3.6), the **license and author symbol are NOT exported**. The Makefile looks like this:

```
ANDROID_EABI := $(ANDROID_NDK)/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin

obj-m += example_module.o
example-objs :=  example-base.o

default:
    $(MAKE) ARCH=arm CFLAGS_MODULE=-fno-pic CROSS_COMPILE=$(ANDROID_EABI)/arm-linux-androideabi- -C $(KDIR_SAMSUNG) M=$(PWD) modules
```

The kernel sources are available in the git repo `https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/samsung.git` by checking out commit `f5f63ef`.

If I build the same module for example for Android kernel `3.1.10-g1e8b3d8` (used for Android 4.3 on Nexus 7) in `https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/tegra.git`, license and author symbol are exported:

```
nm example_module.ko
00000029 r __mod_license360
00000000 r __mod_license753
0000000c r __mod_author361
```

**Does anyone know why the license and author symbol are NOT exported?** I assume it is a kernel problem and not related to Android. AFIK, MODULE_LICENSE was added to the 2.4.10 kernel, so it should work.

I need it, because otherwise the kernel becomes tainted and then I am unable to use `kprobes` in my kernel module:

```
<4>[  454.092541] example: bad vermagic: kernel tainted.
<4>[  454.092709] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
<4>[  454.092895] example: module license 'unspecified' taints kernel.
```

Comment: `nm` lists the symbols you should rather be using `strings example_module.ko | grep GPL`. This should output something like `license=GPL`. For nm "r" The symbol is in a read only data section, but the value is a constant string stored in the text section.

Comment: I agree that your way is correct in terms of looking for the concrete license in `example_module.ko`. However, my problem is that the licence symbol is not exported and thus the module becomes tainted and kprobe handlers cannot be used (just for kernel `2.6.35.7-gf5f63ef` though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `CFLAGS_MODULE=-fno-pic` to `EXTRA_CFLAGS=-fno-pic` in the Makefile solved the problem.